# SCCM WQL Query Structure BIOS release date

Tags: sccm, bios, query, date, vulnerability

So with this whole Meltdown and Spectre causing a huge fuss world wide. I have discovered a solution to mass deploy BIOS updates. The one thing is when checking compliance I am unable to locate anything that is different but the same for all models. What I need is a WQL query that pulls the release date for the BIOS.
You can pull the release date from WMIC, but i cant seem to translate that into WQL to use in SCCM. 
So if someone could toss me an example of a WQL query pulling the BIOS release date.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about WQL is it works from PowerShell as well as in collections and queries.

```
gwmi -namespace root\sms\site_zzz -Query "Select * from SMS_G_System_PC_BIOS"
```

I'm maintaining firmware by creating collections by model, then subcollections by firmware version, such as:

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_PC_BIOS on SMS_G_System_PC_BIOS.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_PC_BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion = "1.18.5"
```

You probably want SMS_G_System_PC_BIOS.ReleaseDate